# (The Homotopy type of the) lifting of homeomorphism of Grassmanian

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, grassmannians

For $k<n$ put $FM_{k\times n}$  for the space of  all $k\times n$ full rank matrices  with real  or  complex  entries.  Note that the permutation group $S_{n}$ has  an  obvious action on this space (with permuting the columns).

On this space, consider the equivalence relation $A\sim B$ iff they have the same *row spaces*. Then the Grassmanian $G(k,n)$ is identified with the quotient $FM_{k\times n}/\sim$.

> Does every homeomorphism of Grassmanian has  a lift to a homeomorphism of $FM_{k\times n}$.
>
> And is it true that this lifted homeomorphism is homotopic or isotopic to a homeomorphism on $FM_{k\times n}$ arising from a permutation of columns?

Comment: For the second question, the answer is no. Consider self-homeomorphism of $G(1,2) \cong S^2$ sending $[z:w]$ to $[\overline z:\overline w]$. This is an orientation-reversing homeomorphism (degree $-1$), and so it does not come from swapping the columns (a complex-analytic homeomorphism, degree $1$).

Comment: @TylerLawson Thanks for your answer to the second question. It arise  a new question: is there  a permutation which is not homotopic to the identity (as  a map on grassmanian)?